# Mac App Store invalid signature issues

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, code-signing

I've recently submitted an application to the Mac App Store and have received an email informing me that the build contains resources (two in total) that carry an invalid signature:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary
>   submission for "X". Your app has proceeded to review, but the
>   following issues should be corrected in your next submission:
>
> Invalid Signature - the nested app bundle Y is not
>   signed, the signature is invalid, or it is not signed with an Apple
>   submission certificate. Refer to the Code Signing and Application
>   Sandboxing Guide for more information.

I've read the linked [Code Signing and Application Sandboxing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html) but am unfortunately none the wiser as to how I'd go about correctly signing these resources. The first is an executable and the second is a framework. Neither of which I compile manually.

What's the correct way of correctly signing these resources?

Comment: Are having the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have embedded Frameworks which are not signed. If are using Xcode with sub projects that are Frameworks or have included frameworks which are copied into the application bundle, they must be code signed.

One simple way around this is to use static libraries instead of Frameworks.

Comment: What if you use Core Data in your bundle and really do not want to use Static Libraries? :/